# Foreign key has implicit reference to object (error in @manytomany Hibernate)

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am beginner in Hibernate and currently facing one error when doing manytomany association with employee  and his skill set. Employee Table is a child class of ValidUser Table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VALIDUSER")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ValidUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="USERID")
private Long userId;
```

My Employee Table is As follows:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USERID")
public class Employee extends ValidUser{

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="REFERCODE")
private Integer referCode;

@Column(name="ISAPPROVED")
private boolean approved;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATEOFBIRTH")
private Date dateOfBirth;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "employee",orphanRemoval = true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<EmployeeSkillSet>skillsSet;
```

Skill Table is:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VALIDSKILLS")
public class ValidSkills {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="SKILLID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="SKILLNAME")
private String skillName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "skill")
private Set<EmployeeSkillSet>skillsSet;
```

EmployeeSkillSet table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEESKILLSET")
public class EmployeeSkillSet {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "EMPSKILLSETID")
private Long empSkillSetId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID") 
private Employee employee;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SKILLID")
private ValidSkills skill;

@Column
private int skillLevel;
```

But when running i am facing error

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table employeeskillset add constraint FKmb3coj44rj4vasva5xe6hvbk8 foreign key (userid) references employee]

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Foreign key 'FKmb3coj44rj4vasva5xe6hvbk8' has implicit reference to object 'employee' which does not have a primary key defined on it.

Please help me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate error: There is no primary key for referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620755/hibernate-error-there-is-no-primary-key-for-referenced-table). Please, use the search feature before asking new questions.

Comment: Hi Andrew Thanks for the comment. But the scenario is different. targetEntity=ValidUser.class solves my problem in EmployeeSkillSet .